# Why are there holes in these green radishes?

Tags: vegetables, root-vegetables, carrots, radishes

[image: green radishes]

I was at my local supermarket when I noticed these green radishes which all had these holes in their sides as seen in the photo. The skin of the radishes around the holes look too smooth to have been created by hand, so I was wondering whether this is something that occurred naturally when the radishes were growing, or if it was something artificially done to the radishes for some reason.

I looked up pictures of green radishes on Google but none of the pictures showed any holes in the radishes, which only makes me even more curious. If anyone who stumbles upon this post has an answer to satisfy my curiosity that would be awesome!

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if they were planted with a rod under them, so the root eventually grew around it. Perhaps to make harvesting easier, or maybe just for the novelty value.

Comment: This is a type of bug I forget the name of it but that is damage caused by its larva could you maybe look for a beetle or worm to give a better idea of what is in your garden. Also a relative size I am assuming the holes are the size of dimes correct? Another thing is where are these radishes being grown (country of origin)? What is the climate like ?   I could give you an answer based on where I live bit that may not apply to where you are located.

Comment: Also if you could slice one open vertically meaning top to bottom that will help give a general idea of what went on in the radish aka where the bug entered the plant and where it exited the plant.

Comment: The bottom line it is some kind of worm or larva and that is either the exit or entry hole.

Comment: It's hard to believe these are natural. They are exactly the same size and in exactly the same position in every radish. And supermarkets usually only sell "perfect" produce, not  something damaged by pests or diseases. The holes look like they were created with a coring tool, but I have no idea why anybody would do that.

Comment: So I went back to supermarket today and compared the holes in the radishes. They are indeed the size of dimes. The radishes originated from China, so it's probably a cool climate.